# Как правильно оформить плейлист js с цикла PHP?

Tags: javascript, php

Есть такой код плейлиста js лежит в PHP.

```
echo '[
    {"title":"Любая озвучка",".'$ozvychka'.":
        [
            {"title":"# сезон",".'$sezon'.":
                [
                    {"title":"# серия","file":".'$seria'."},
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]';
```

Допустим я беру из API Json количество [], пример озвучек у данного материала 3, а сезонов 4, серий 11. Как правильно тут работать с циклом PHP и вывести в данные переменные `$ozvychka, $sezon, $seria` разные количества, чтобы не нарушить скобки JS плейлиста? Я просто не представляю ну или плохо думаю.

**P.S 
Еще пример как должен работать плейлист автоматически а не вручную прописать. Просто я не понимаю как правильно вывести такое количество**

```
echo '[
Цикл 1 > {"title":"LostFilm",".'$ozvychka'.":
    [
        Цикл 2 > {"title":"1 сезон",".'$sezon'.":
            [
               Цикл 3 > {"title":"1 серия","file":".'файл'."},
                        {"title":"2 серия","file":".'файл'."},
                        {"title":"2 серия","file":".'файл'."}, Конец цикла 3.
            ]
        } Конец цикла 2.
        Цикл 2 > {"title":"2 сезон",".'$sezon'.":
            [
               Цикл 3 > {"title":"1 серия","file":".'файл'."}, Конец цикла 3.
            ]
        } Конец цикла 2.
    ]
} < Конец цикла 1.
]';
```

**Пример исходного кода из json**

```
    Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [title] => Флэш 
            [kinopoisk_id] => 817506
            [quality] => хорошее HD
            [seasons] => 5
            [episodes] => 7
            [iframe] => ссылка
            [translator] => ColdFilm
        )
    )
```

Из этого iframe_url в ссылке с помощью `fie_get_contents` я парсю с помощью `preg_match` ссылки серийные к сериям, я это знаю как делать, но вывести в скобу серий в код JS не понимаю. Я пробовал через `for` через такое количество `count()` сначала выводит 2 озвучки, потом скобка нарушена, и пытаюсь вывести количество 4 сезона через `for`, я понимаю, что это вложенный цикл, выводит всего около 8. Я просто мало занимаюсь программированием, но это мой первый проект, пока что с фильмом получилось, а вот сериалы с плейлистами сложная схема.

Comment: И все же не совсем понятно, что именно вы хотите сделать. О каком цикле вы говорите. Вы можете работать с массивами самого PHP и в нужный момент (например, во время передачи клиенту) обернуть массив в `json_encode()` и массив сам преобразуется в валидную json строку.

Comment: @Misha не могу объяснить в комментариях подробнее, раз новый пример еще написал, посмотри может поймешь.

Comment: не надо пытаться выводить json руками. соберите нужный массив, закодируйте в json, и выведите что получилось.

Comment: приведите пример ваших исходных данных этих самых переменных, что у вас там?

Comment: @teran я вывел пример еще раз, жду от вас комментарий.